# Is it possible to launch a program from the TFS portal from a link or button on the dashboard?

Tags: tfs, markdown

Interested in trying to launch an email link where it launches Outlook and populates the recipients with the grp email account. Or something like a link to launch Notepad. I've done some looking and the best thing I've found that doesn't work is this in markup.

```
[Launch Notepad](file://c:/windows/notepad.exe)
```

Do you know if this is possible, and what is the method to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to send an email from a link, you want to use `mailto:` protocol links https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto